# Installing drivers on my nvidia graphics card. One command claims I have proper drivers the other one contradicts

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have tried many methods to install drivers. Using ppa, using .run file, using terminal autoinstall. Nothing seems to work

when I input:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```

I get:

```
ii  libnvidia-compute-460:amd64                460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-460:i386                 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-460                   460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-dkms-460                            460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-460                   460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-prime                               0.8.15.3~0.20.04.1                    all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
rc  nvidia-settings                            440.82-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

It claims that I have the drivers installed. But when I input:

```
$ inxi -G
```

I get:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] driver: N/A 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: fbdev,nouveau 
  unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~77Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.1 256 bits) 
  v: 4.5 Mesa 21.1.0-devel (git-0a7224f 2021-02-28 focal-oibaf-ppa)
```

It says the driver for my graphics card is N/A in the second line. I have spent hours trying different installation methods and deleting my drivers and reinstalling them. I am wondering if there is something that I am missing. And yes the 460 is the recommended driver for GP106. Thanks!

Comment: @Terrance, yes I did. Do you mind me asking? What difference does this make?? Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `dpkg` the `rc` status means a package has been removed but the configuration files are still in place or the package isn't fully installed while the `ii` status indicates that a package is installed.

It should also be noted that the proprietary Nvidia graphics drivers are now included with the default repositories and no PPA is required.

To automatically install the correct driver(s), run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

You can also run the following for more information:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers list
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

In any case, the 460 appears to be the correct driver as listed on the Nvidia website.

**EDIT:**

Since you are using the Nvidia 460 DKMS package, you might need to disable secure boot as a workaround if you encounter issues.

In the mean time, you should open a new question to address the unsigned kernel module issue with DKMS so you don't have to disable secure boot. The process usually involves disabling secure boot, then booting up the computer, and signing or trusting the modules while secure boot disabled. After that, you should be able to log out (power down), enable secure boot, and then log back in.

Comment: The solution for me was to disable secure boot. If anyone has my issue, try to disable secure boot in BIOS

Comment: Thanks for the update. I added some information regarding secure boot. This is a common issue when installing a DKMS package like this. I suggest opening a question concerning the unsigned kernel module (probably what the issue is). I'm pretty sure there's an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using X.org and not Wayland, NVIDIA doesn't support waylandn at the moment.
Make sure you installed the correct drivers, you will probably need nvidia-3xx or nvidia-driver-4xx. Everything depends on your model.
You can use "lspci | grep VGA" to know your nvidia model, or ubuntu-drivers devices
then run: sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall, this option automatically detects your card and install drivers for it.
Or if you have and specific version you can run "sudo apt install nvidia-yourmodel"
You can also add this ppa to install drivers :)
sudo add-apt-repository ppa: graphics-drivers / ppa

Comment: @Ricky_Navarro hey, thanks for your answer. When I run that command, I get ```01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] (rev a1)```, I'm not really sure what that means or how to convert this information into knowing what driver I need to install. my model is just GP106???? I see this is kind of answered above.. but I don't quite get what part is the model

Comment: GeForce GTX 1060 is the model, the GP106 is the family of card it belongs too. The important part in selecting the driver, it needs to support the family of card you have.